# RecyclerView Adapter and one to many data

Tags: android

I have a Database with contacts and phone numbers. Every contact can have multiple phone numbers. After correctly displaying all the contacts from the Contacts table, I wanted to add the phone numbers matching to the contacts in the same view.

I thought that I could do this by creating a Coursor to the phone numbers of the current contact inside of `onBindViewHolder` and adding them to a prepared LinearLayout inside my contact element (the main element of the RecyclerView)

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position){
    if (mCursorContacts != null) {
        mCursorContacts.moveToPosition(position);
        String name = mCursorContacts.getString(mCursorContacts.getColumnIndex(PingContract.ContactEntry.COLUMN_NAME));
        String system_contact_id = mCursorContacts.getString(mCursorContacts.getColumnIndex(PingContract.ContactEntry.COLUMN_SYSTEM_ID));
        // Code to add phone numbers to contacts
        Cursor phoneNumberCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(PingContract.ContactPhoneEntry.buildContactPhoneUri(0),
                null,
                PingContract.ContactPhoneEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_ID + " = " + system_contact_id,
                null,
                null);
        int i = 0;
        while(phoneNumberCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String phoneNumber =
                    String.valueOf(
                            phoneNumberCursor.getString(
                                    phoneNumberCursor.getColumnIndex(
                                            PingContract.ContactPhoneEntry.COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER)));
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, phoneNumber);
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.phone_number_item_with_button, null);
            TextView phoneNumberTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone_number_text_view);
            phoneNumberTextView.setText(phoneNumber);
            holder.mContactPhoneNumberWithButton.addView(view, i++);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(i));
        }
        phoneNumberCursor.close();
        // end of code to add phone numbers
        holder.mFirstLetter.setImageDrawable(TextDrawable.builder().buildRound(Character.toString(name.charAt(0)), Color.BLACK));
        holder.mNameTextView.setText(name);
    }
}
```

At first this seems to work, however when scrolling, more and more phone numbers are being added to the contacts. I assume this has something to do with Android predicting how far the scroll can move the list and running the `onBindViewHolder` ahead of time to allow a smooth scroll. So this is clearly not the way to go.

The question then is, what is the correct way to display one-to-many sort of data in a single RecyclerView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best source for this would be the [default Contacts app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/) of Android. But it's using a `ListView` instead.

Your problem with the expanding data is directly related to your view holders and binding to these. You're adding views to the `mContactPhoneNumberWithButton` layout without ever removing them again. If it only contains phone number text views, you could just empty it on binding.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mContactPhoneNumberWithButton.removeAllViews();
    [...]
}
```

But querying a content resolver inside should be avoided anyway. Instead prepare your model completely at once at the beginning.

Comment: Ok, but if I join those tables wouldn't i get a new record for every phone number? Then I'd get "duplicate" contacts with different phone numbers, and not a single contact with multiple phone numbers. How would you resolve this issue?

Comment: You'd need to pre-process the data you receive. Joining would be one possibility. Doing separate calls another. Like you're doing, only before the binding. Or have a look how the Android Guys do it.

Comment: This is probably just me being inexperienced, but how would you do that with a join (which seems to be the simplest solution) You would need to collapse multiple records into one to get a single contact with multiple values. If I'd do it with two queries, how could I do the query for the phone numbers, while not knowing whose phone number's i'm looking for (not being in `onBindViewHolder` where I have access to this information). Do you maybe have a sample?

Comment: Don't have any samples, sorry. I'd query all contacts and all phone numbers and try to use [CursorJoiner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorJoiner.html) to get all results. Then I'd fill a custom model with the data.

Comment: Sorry for the late follow up, but why did you say that "If it only contains phone number text views, you could just empty it on binding."? Does this mean that if it contains something else (e.g. buttons) I'm going to run into problems?

Comment: You would have to setup these views after `removeAllViews()` again, or only remove the phone number views differently. But if the layout only contains the phone number views, you wouldn't have to worry about removing views you actually don't want to remove.